# Why UITableView contentOffset varies wildly during tableview reloadData instead of just stay the same? How to make it stay the same after reloadData?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm browsing internet with no satisfying result. I have a `tableView`, whose offset always changed erratically whenever I do `reloadData`. This happens even when the contents of the table stays the same.

I put a code to record how the offset changes while running `reloadData` using `scrollViewDidScroll`.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print ("TABLEVIEW OFFSET : \(scrollView.contentOffset)");
}
```

I also create a code to save the old offset before reloadData, and re-set to the new offset after a delay.

```
extension UITableView {

    func reloadDataOffset() {
        print ("OLD OFFSET : \(self.contentOffset)");
        let offset = self.contentOffset;
        let oldHidden = self.isHidden;
        self.isHidden = true;
        self.reloadData();
        delay(1) {
            self.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false);
            self.isHidden = oldHidden;
            print ("NEW OFFSET : \(self.contentOffset)");
        }
    }

}
```

This is what appears on the log.

```
OLD OFFSET : (0.0, 314.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, -64.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 314.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, -64.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 753.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 586.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 753.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 706.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 753.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 751.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 750.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 747.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 744.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 741.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 737.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 733.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 729.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 725.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 721.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 717.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 714.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 711.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 709.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 707.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 706.5)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 706.0)
TABLEVIEW OFFSET : (0.0, 314.0)
NEW OFFSET : (0.0, 314.0)
```

I did this (add delay) because I read somewhere that the tableView reloadData happens in different thread, and that I cannot exactly get a callback or notification whenever reloadData is finish. But this looks ugly as hell. I can remove the `isHidden = true` part, but that will make the table content looks jumping around. Is there any true way where I can re-set the offset to the old value as soon as the reloadData finish? Or, is there any way I can make the scroll offset stay in place before/after reloadData?

Comment: @matt even if I strip away all the `print`, the result is still the same, jittery and jumping all everywhere.

Comment: For those who vote to close my question because it's unclear, I thought I have made the question as clear as I can in the question title itself. Please inform me in which part it is unclear, and let me fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix it after I call this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

Looks like this is a new default 'obscure features' of iOS 11 that in my case doing more damage than helping. That's why I never encountered this problem before iOS 11. This estimations messing up with my table content size and content offset controls. Try turning these three estimations off, and you'll see `UITableView` erratic `contentOffset` or `contentSize` will behave under your control again. I just really wish that Apple made features like this defaulted to disabled when added, to not mess with older codes that didn't prepare for this new changes.

Comment: I suspect your tableview does not know exactly the height of your cells.

Comment: @CynichniyBandera I forgot to mention above that I also already implement "heightForRow" function. But the tableView seems to not use that as reference when calculating `contentSize` or `contentOffset` when doing `reloadData`.